# PHP PDO Transaction with nested PHP check

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have to do 2 MySql-queries:

1. SELECT id FROM X WHERE [...]
2. INSERT [...]

The second query should only be executed, if the first query returns an correct id.

Is it possible, to mix PHP conditions between both queries?

Eg.

```
try
{   
    $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $dbh->beginTransaction();   

    $stmt =  $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM [...]");

    $stmt->bindParam(1, [...]);

    if($stmt->execute())
    {
        if($row = $stmt->fetch())
        {
            $matchID = $row['id'];
            $checkD = $this->checkId($matchID);

            if($checkD)
            {
                return '-1';
            }
            else
            {       

                $stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO [...]");

                $stmt->bindParam(1,[...]);
                $stmt->execute();

                            stmt = $dbh->prepare("DELETE [...]");

                $stmt->bindParam(1,[...]);
                $stmt->execute();

                $dbh->commit();

                return $matchID;                            
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return '-1';
        }
    }
    else
    {
        return '-1';
    }       
} catch(Exception $e)
{
    $dbh->rollBack();
    return '-1';
}
```

Is this correct? (i get zero errors)
If not: how can i realize it?

I want to be sure, that no other user could reach the INSERT query, when annother is performing the 1. query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transactions are isolated from the current data. How they behave exactly is dependent on the [isolation level](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/transaction-iso.html) they use. For example a transaction with serializable isolation level completely lives in the past, and it knows nothing of the data changes have been made since the beginning of the transaction.

If you want to prevent anybody to do changes on the database while your script is working on something, then you have to [lock](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/locking-issues.html) your database, tables or rows. This is usually not necessary, with the proper code.

In your case

- you can use read committed transaction isolation level (default) call the `DELETE` after the `SELECT`, and check whether there are affected rows by the `DELETE` before the `INSERT`
- if you don't want to change the order of your queries then you can

  - simply throw an exception if the `DELETE` does not affect any row, and so the `INSERT` will be rolled back
  - add a constraint which prevents multiple `INSERT`s with the same data, so the duplicated `INSERT` will violate a constraint, and it will be rolled back
  - lock the rows with a [`SELECT FOR UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-locking-reads.html)

Comment: I think, throwing an exception will be the best choice. Thank you :) I reposted this question with more background (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24035675/some-mysql-queries-with-php-condition?noredirect=1#comment37053378_24035675) some minutes ago. Do you think, there is a "the best" solution?

Comment: I think you should avoid locking if possible, because it slows down your application. I'd use constraints if possible, if not, then exceptions. But that's just my opinion, it is hard to choose since I am not a db expert. By small applications I don't think it does matter.

Answer (score -1):

This rather makes no sense. there is no use for transactions at all. What you want to roll back? a SELECT query result?

> I want to be sure, that no other user could reach the INSERT query, when another is performing the 1. query.

This is achieved via table locking, not transactions. Or, rather by the simple key uniqueness. Without knowing your business logic it's impossible to answer more. Better ask another question, explaining user experience, and avoiding technical terms like "transaction" at all.

Comment: My problem: a user checks, it the specific id is correct. If true, then the INSERT should be executed. Then the id entry should be deleted. How can i be sure, that no other user gets the id, before it is deleted by the first user? The insert should be excecuted just one time.

Comment: This cleared nothing, sorry. In general, you have to lock table to restrict other processes from accessing it.

Comment: Ok, i will open a new question with more background. Thank you :)